# LOF and LOT in two columns with different Names in TOC, in headmark an on Page

Tags: table-of-contents, multicol

There is a TableOfContent, a ListOfFigures and a ListOfTables.

The LOF and the LOT are on one page in two columns (multicols).
They should have short names as Headline ("Figures" and "Tables")
In the TOC they should shown with two entries ("List Of Figures" ans "List Of "Tables"), of cause the have the same pagenumber ;-)
The Headmark on their page should have the description "List of Figures and Tables"

```
 \documentclass[12pt,DIV=10,ngerman,headings = normal,listof = totoc,bibliography = totoc,index = totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength{\topskip}{\ht\strutbox} % behebt Warnung von geometry
\geometry{paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm,headheight=30mm}   
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\clearpairofpagestyles 

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark{chapter}
\automark*{section}


\ihead{\headmark} 
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\begin{document} 

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table Of Content} 
\tableofcontents{}

\newpage

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List Of Figures} 
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figures}
    \label{Figures}
    \listoffigures{}     
    \vfill\null
    \columnbreak
    \begingroup
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List Of Tables}
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}
    \label{Tables}
    \listoftables{}       
    \endgroup
\end{multicols}


\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{figure ONE}  
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h] 
\begin{tabular}{l} 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table  ONE} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might use paracol instead of multicol, especially if they span multiple pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks strange for me. But you can remove option `listof=totoc` and use option `headings=optiontoheadandtoc` and `\deftocheading` to get the desired result.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,headings = normal,bibliography = totoc,index = totoc,
  headings=optiontoheadandtoc% <- added
]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed with outdated TeX-distributions
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\setlength{\topskip}{\ht\strutbox} % behebt Warnung von geometry???
\geometry{paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm,headheight=30mm}
\usepackage[headsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles 
\automark{chapter}
\automark*{section}
\ihead{\headmark} 
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\deftocheading{toc}{%
  \addchap[tocentry={Table of Contents}]{\contentsname}%
}
\deftocheading{lof}{%
  \addchap[tocentry=\listfigurename,head={List of Figures and Tables}]{Figures}%
}
\deftocheading{lot}{%
  \addchap[tocentry=\listtablename,head={List of Figures and Tables}]{Tables}%
}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \listoffigures
  \vfill
  \columnbreak
  \begingroup
  \let\clearpage\relax
  \listoftables
  \vfill
  \endgroup
\end{multicols}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{figure ONE}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{l}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table ONE}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!
I just add "\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figures}" again to name the lists in the TOC in my language.